# How can I do a Static Image Export on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, plotly-python, orca

I'm trying to export an image I've created with plotly as a .svg file.

This is the code I'm running to export it:

```
fig.write_image("/content/fig1.svg")
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image: Error - part 1]

[image: Error - part 2]

I've entered in the github page of Orca and tried to use the installation codes they suggest but neither one worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install orca with the following code. (a library I wrote)

```py
!pip install kora -q
import kora.install.orca
```

Then it can write_image

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure( go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,3,2] ) )
fig.write_image("image.png")
from IPython.display import Image
Image("image.png")
```

If you prefer to install orca yourself

```
import os
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
url = "https://github.com/plotly/orca/releases/download/v1.2.1/orca-1.2.1-x86_64.AppImage"
orca = '/usr/local/bin/orca'
urlretrieve(url, orca)
os.chmod(orca, 0o755)
os.system("apt install xvfb libgconf-2-4")
```